# Generate build info source file in Maven project (similar to SBT Buildinfo)

Tags: maven, sbt-buildinfo

I used to use https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo to generate source code files in my Scala project to access information such as the project version from within the code.
SBT BuildInfo generates code that looks like the following:

```
case object BuildInfo {
  val name: String = "helloworld"
  /** The value is "0.1-SNAPSHOT". */
  val version: String = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  ...
}
```

I need to do the same in a Maven project.
I tried to use mvn `artifact:buildinfo` which generates similar information, but the output is a plaintext file non-acceessible from within the code (it also uses non-static naming, making it annoyingly difficult to find programmatically):

`helloworld-0.1-SNAPSHOT.buildinfo`

```
name=helloworld
group-id=com.my-group
artifact-id=helloworld
version=0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

My final goal is to be able to display such information on the application startup splash screen.

Example:

```
private def printBannerAndBuildInfo(): Unit = {
println(banner)
println(s"""Build information:
             |  Version         : ${BuildInfo.version}
             |  Scala version   : ${BuildInfo.scalaVersion}
             |  JDK version     : ${BuildInfo.jdkVersion}
             |  Git commit hash : ${BuildInfo.gitCommitHash}
             |  Git work dir    : ${if (BuildInfo.gitWorkDirStatus) "clean" else "dirty"}
         """.stripMargin)
 }
```

Is there anything readily available to achieve so in a Maven project?
Thanks

Comment: I have a prototype that I did recently for generating Java source with git information in it at compile time.  You might find it useful - comments are welcome.  https://github.com/ravn/gaps

Comment: Hi @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, thank you, I will follow your project. 
It would give me part of the information I need, unfortunately I am still working in a Java 8 project

Comment: But what do you need to know?

Comment: I made it work with Java 8. 